# Passing DataTable Column Type to generic method <T>

Tags: c#, .net, generic-type-argument

I have a method declared as such

```
public static T GetValidatedValue<T>(string param)
{
   do something here and return object of type T...;
}
```

usually I call it like this   var somnum = GetValidatedValue("14");
and expect sumNum to be number or if an invalid value was passed to be "0"

my problem now is that I need to pass a datatabel column type as "T" into this method

something like :

```
dr[col] = GetValidatedValue <typeof(dr[col])>(dr[col].ToString());
```

this will not compile

it is basicaly a combination of two(2) methods that I have found somewhere(maybe even on this site) and modified to work as i needed

```
public static T GetValidatedValue<T>(string param)
{
    return TryParse<T>(param);
}

private static T TryParse<T>(string inValue)
{
    var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));

    try
    {
        return (T)converter.ConvertFromString(null, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,     inValue);
    }
    catch
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

can anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong...

Comment: So the method is supposed to parse a String into a number of various types?

Comment: yes, but it actually work with any types. it is basicaly a combination of two(2) methods that I have found somewhere(maybe even on this site) and modified to work as i needed          public static T GetValidatedValue<T>(string param){return TryParse<T>(param);}
private static T TryParse<T>(string inValue)
{
  var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
  try{
      return (T)converter.ConvertFromString(null, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, inValue);
            }
            catch
            {
                return default(T);
            }
        }

Comment: could you please edit that into your question?

Comment: Maybe, and I'm just pulling at straws here so I'm not posting this as an answer, try using dr[col].GetType() or if worst comes to worst, make the return type object. Let us know if it works.

Comment: Now I'm confused why yo are converting the value to a string, and then converting back to that value - `dr[col] = GetValidatedValue <typeof(dr[col])>(dr[col].ToString());`

Comment: this was an example. I am trying to make sure that DataTable does not have any nulls in any of the columns before I assign it to the report datasource.  if any columns have null values the report errors out. so I though I will loop though all the columns row by row and update the value if it is null to a default as in 0 - for numeric types, date.min for dates, emptystring for strings.

Comment: I tried everything I could think of Michael, nothing is working.   also problem is not the return type by the <T> designator to indicate what type I want to process

Answer (score 0):

How about the KISS method:

```
static readonly Dictionary<Type, object> defaultMap = new Dictionary<Type, object>()
        {
            { typeof(DateTime), DateTime.MinValue },
            { typeof(Int32), 0},
            { typeof(String), ""}
            /* etc etc etc*/
        };

private static void SetDefault(Type type, ref object value)
{
    if(value == DBNull.Value || value == null)
        value = defaultMap[type];
}
```

Then you just call it:

```
SetDefault(col.DataType, ref dr[col]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generics are really only useful when you know what the type will be at compile time, in which case you can call your method like this:

```
GetValidatedValue<int>(dr[col].ToString());
```

However, it looks to me like you don't actually know the type at compile time, so generics would only get in the way. Try implementing a non-generic version of your method, like this:

```
public static object GetValidatedValue(string param, Type type)
{
    return TryParse(param, type);
}

private static object TryParse(string inValue, Type type)
{
    var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type);

    try
    {
        return converter.ConvertFromString(null, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, inValue);
    }
    catch
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

That way you can call it like this:

```
GetValidatedValue<int>(dr[col].ToString(), dr[col].GetType());
```

(Although I must admit it seems like unnecessary overhead to turn something into a string and then convert it back to its original type again.)

#### Update

Now that I better understand what you're trying to do, the above method won't work because `dr[col]` will not have *any* type if it is `null`, and it will have the `DbNull` type if it is `DbNull`. Unless you have some other way to determine what type of data *should* be stored in that column, it's just not going to work. Of course, if you *can* figure out what data type should be there, getting the default value will be totally easy:

```
public static object GetValidatedValue(string param, Type type)
{
    return param == null || param == DBNull.Value ? Activator.CreateInstance(type); 
}
```